# How to call a variable inside main function from another program in python?

Tags: python

I have two python files first.py and second.py

first.py looks like

```
def main():
  #some computation
  first_variable=computation_result
```

second.py looks like

```
import first
def main():
  b=getattr(first, first_variable)
  #computation
```

but I am getting No Attribute error. Is there any way to access a variable inside main() method in first.py through second.py?

Answer (score 4):

You should use function calls and return values instead of this.

Return the computation_result from the function in the first file, and then store the result in the b variable in the second file.

first.py

```
def main():
    # computation
    return computation_result
```

second.py

```
import first
def main():
    b = first.main()
```

Other option is to use a global variable in the first file where you will store the value and later reference it.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to read [9.1 and 9.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) in the Tutorial and [Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) in the Language Reference.

In your example `first_variable` only *exists* within `first.main()`'s local scope - while it is executing. It isn't accessible to anything outside of that scope.

---

You need to get  `first_variable` into `first`'s global scope - then in `second` you can use it with `first.first_variable`.

One way would be to return something from `first.main()` and assign it to `first_variable`.

```
def main():
    return 2

first_variable = main()
```

Then in `second` you can use it:

```
import first
times_3 = first.first_variable * 3
```